# I want to create custom menu & also add submenu in it. In sub menu, I want to add my all sheet name automatically in google sheet

Tags: javascript, google-sheets

I'm trying to all sheet name add automatically in sub menu of my custom menu. Please solve this. I tried too many times.

```
installFunctions(); // This is required to run the function. So please don't remove this.
function onOpen_panda() {} // This can be used as the simple trigger.

function installFunctions() { 
  const menu = SpreadsheetApp.getUi().createMenu('sample menu').addSubMenu('Sheet List');
  const ss = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSpreadsheet();
  ss.getSheets().forEach(s => {
    if (!s.isSheetHidden()) {
      const name = s.getSheetName();
      const functionName = `sample${Utilities.base64Encode(name).replace(/[=+\/]/g, "")}`;
      this[functionName] = () => ss.getSheetByName(name).activate();
      menu.addItem(name, functionName);
    }
  })
  menu.addToUi();
}
```

Comment: Can you provide a sanitized copy of the spreadsheet¿

Comment: Yes I'm adding sheet

Comment: https://docs.google.com/spreadsheets/d/1MEfxaVTlcpYTj0YhTlqZJmG3PPMsC20Gmznc0H7wmRI/edit?usp=drivesdk

Comment: The Google Sheet is not accessible. please update the sharing permissions.